# Storing all the events that happened inside a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way to store all the window form events inside a list, so all of those events can be reapplied when the user opens the form next time?

**Example:** Let's say the user clicks a button inside a form and types in a string and then closes the form. After a while the user reopens the application again, and the form is re-initialized so that the click action and the string the user input is restored. (Kind of like an auto-save function.)

Purpose for this:

- Recover after suspension.
- Allow user to undo their work (Undo Button).

Comment: No offense, but your English is not very clear.  Please try to elaborate.  I think you are saying that if you enter something in a textbox on a secondary form (because usually when you close the primary form, the application exits) and close that secondary form, on reopening, the textbox retains the previous value.  Is that correct?  This indeed can be done.

Comment: In addition to @GrayFox374's comments, how will you be storing the event list in between sessions? Is this app connected to a database or will you be writing to a file?

Comment: @GrayFox374 sorry about the wording, i will edit my post now

Comment: It seems to me your question isn't really about "saving events", but about saving the **state** of your form. In other words, you don't care how the form got there, but you want to know what it contains and be able to restore it to that condition?

Comment: You would need a onclick event for all the possible actions a user can do. You would then have to save those into a file before closing the app. On the next load you would then have to read the file and "re-create" the form

Comment: @JamieBabineau how about the typing part? As well, storing it in a file? text file? how would you accomplish that?

Comment: Text is trickier but there are a couple ways to handle it. You could do it on TextChange or LosesFocus. The only thing about LoseFocus is it will only fire when you click out of the textbox and theres no guarantee that your user will click off the textbox

Comment: @JamieBabineau so even if i call those event, do i store them in a list and inside a text file? Should i store them as string?

Comment: well if you plan on restoring the form after the application is closed you need to save it to a file of some sort and the possibilities are numerous it all depends how you want to handle that. But if its only a particular form of your app and you don't plan on restoring it after the application is closed you could store it in a list or dictionary and the value would depend on what you are asking from your user but string is safer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure I understand you, but you say you want to get a list of events, okay, that can be done using Reflection.  Here is a good link:  http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-reflection-to-get-object-information

Your example:

> Let's say the user clicks a button inside a form and type in a string,
>   he then closes the form, after a while he open the application again,
>   and form can re-initialize the form and apply the click action and the
>   string he inputted(kind of like an auto-save function).

-You can do this without getting a list of events.  So I don't see why you have to do it this way.  There are multiple ways to do this.  If you are using a winform, one basic solution is to define properties using the settings page.  Check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cftf714c(VS.90).aspx

Use the Settings page of the Project Designer to specify a project's application settings. Application settings enable you to store and retrieve property settings and other information for your application dynamically. They also enable you to maintain custom application and user preferences on a client computer. For more information, see Application Settings.

> To access the Settings page, select a project node in Solution
>   Explorer, and then, on the Project menu, click Properties. When the
>   Project Designer appears, click the Settings tab.

You can establish waypoints (to borrow a term from aviation) and save values to your settings collection periodically without the user having to do anything, like they would have to do if you provided a save button.  But that just brings up the point, what's wrong will the lowly save button.  It's a well known convention. People know that if they don't want to lose data, they should save every now and then.